# Showing description instead of id when selecting a promptdialog.choice option in Bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I have implemented code in the BOT framework like this way and when I will click a particular choice I want to see the description instead of id . How to do that?

```
PromptDialog.Choice(
                            context: context,
                            resume: getSpeciaLities,
                             options: customerdata.Select(p => p.Id).ToArray(),
                          prompt: "Hi. Please Select client name",
                          retry: "Selected plan not avilabel . Please try again.",
                          promptStyle: PromptStyle.Auto,
                          descriptions: customerdata.Select(p => p.ClientName).ToArray()
                            );
```

Thanks
Utpal Maity

Comment: Could you please try to elaborate on your question, it is not clear what you are asking.  the ID field you are using is on some custom object, while the description is on the prompt itself.  This makes it unclear what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

> when I will click a particular choice I want to see the description instead of id

If you’d like to display the `ClientName` in chat window instead of `Id` when user click a particular option, you can directly provide all ClientNames of your `customerdata` as **options** for **PromptDialog.Choice**.

And if you want to do another operations/business logic based on the `Id` of selected option, you can retrieve it from `customerdata` based on that specific ClientName you selected.

```
var customerdata = GetCustomerdata();

PromptDialog.Choice(
        context: context,
        resume: ChoiceReceivedAsync,
        options: customerdata.Select(p => p.ClientName).ToArray(),
        prompt: "Hi. Please Select Client Nanme:",
        retry: "Selected plan not avilabel . Please try again.",
        promptStyle: PromptStyle.Auto,
        descriptions: customerdata.Select(p => p.ClientName).ToArray()
        );
```

*In ChoiceReceivedAsync method:*

```
private async Task ChoiceReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
{
    string response = await result;

    var customerdata = GetCustomerdata();

    //retrieve the id of selected option

    var id = customerdata.Where(p => p.ClientName == response).Select(r => r.Id).FirstOrDefault();

    //your business logic here

    await context.PostAsync($"Id is {id} and ClientName is {response}");
}
```

*Test result:*

[image]